# google maps how can I zoom out by default?

Tags: google-maps

I created a new google map and added a few markers however when I include it in my code with iframe it starts with zoom as 17 and I want it zoomed out max (z=20). I tried to pass the argument z=20 but with no result. Any suggestions?
code:

```
<iframe width="425" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=204116165110023160774.0004d7aa572501051bc40&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.020098,-95.625&amp;spn=116.710475,270.527344&amp;t=m&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Comment: what is the iframe code you're using?

Comment: @AlexOlder, the code was in the question it just didn't have the `code block` formatting around it

Comment: yes, there code is in the question. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it when you create your map :

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(map, {
        zoom: 20,
        center: latLng, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
```